# How to pause Thread::Queue access while waiting for prior threads to finish up?

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue

So this is what I have right now:

```
for my $action (@actionList){
  $q->enqueue([$_, $action]) for @component_dirs;

  print "\nWaiting for prior actions to finish up...\n";
  until (!defined($q->peek())) {}
}

$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

But this doesn't seem to work.. is there a better way to force the queue to wait for previous `$action` items to complete before allowing access again?

**edit:** Oddly enough, it's magically started working... maybe it was working all along and I just didn't make the output apparent enough. Either way, my question still stands - is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't wait until the previous action has completed, it just wastes CPU until another thread starts working on the last job.

For things like “flags”, you should generally use semaphores instead. Semaphores are thread-safe counters with `up` and `down` methods. For example, we could pass a semaphore along with the job, which starts with count zero. Each thread increments the semaphore when it finishes a job. Our main thread tries to decrement the semaphore by the count of jobs, which will block until all threads have finished:

```
my $q = Thread::Queue->new;
my @workers = map { threads->create(\&worker, $q) } 1 .. $NUM_WORKERS;

for my $action (@actionList) {
    my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new(0);
    $q->enqueue([$_, $action, $sem]) for @component_dirs;
    $sem->down(0+@component_dirs);  # wait for the threads
}

$q->end;
$_->join for @workers;

sub worker {
    my ($q) = @_;
    while (my $job = $q->dequeue) {
        my ($component, $action, $sem) = @$job;
        ...
        $sem->up;
    }
}
```

Actually, we could reuse the semaphore.

See the [`Thread::Semaphore` docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread%3a%3aSemaphore) for more details.

This usage is similar to [barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Thank you - any specific reason to do `->down(0+@component_dirs)` rather than just `->down(@component_dirs)`?

Comment: Because I want to decrement by the size of the array, and need to impose scalar context for that. So we could also say `->down(scalar @component_dirs)`, but I find `0+` clearer in this case.